# Data Binding in C#, what this code does?

Tags: c#, data-binding

I'm a beginner in C# and reading about data binding. My book introduces with the starting code like this:

```
// Create object (width, text, color)

TextParms tp = new TextParms(200, "Casablanca", Color.Beige);

// Bind text and BackColor properties of control

txtMovie.DataBindings.Add("Text", tp, "Tb_Text"); // line 2
```

What does `line 2` actually do? Where did the parameters `Text` and `Tb_Text` come from? What are their uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`txtMovie.DataBindings.Add("Text", tp, "Tb_Text")`

Looking at the documentation of [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wkkxwcz.aspx)

```
public Binding(
    string propertyName,
    Object dataSource,
    string dataMember
)
```

- **Text** is a property of probably your **txtMovie** object
- **datasource** in your **tp** is the source of your databinding
- **Tb_Text** is a datamember of your TextParams class.

Answer (score 1):

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6y3aby2.aspx

```
public Binding Add(
    string propertyName,
    Object dataSource,
    string dataMember
)
```

Parameters:

```
_propertyName_ 
Type: System.String 
The name of the control property to bind. 

_dataSource_ 
Type: System.Object
An Object that represents the data source. 

_dataMember_ 
Type: System.String 
The property or list to bind to.
```

Comment: now my question is both the `_propertyName_ ` and `_dataMember_` names are user defined?

Comment: I haven't worked with DataBindings that much, but I guess it binds the `Tb_Text` column of your data source to the `Text` property of the `txtMovie` control.